# finding all functions: $f(\frac{x+a}{b})=f(\frac{f(x)+a}{b})$,$f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions

If i have this equation: $f(\frac{x+a}{b})=f(\frac{f(x)+a}{b})$ such that $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ , $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Need to find all functions there are in this way.

So i can choose $a=c-f(x)$ then $f( (x-f(x))/b + c/b ) = f(c/b)$

So adding $(x-f(x))/b$ doesn't changing the value in point $c/b$ and it's almost a general point.

But i can't see how to to continue and if there any solution that is not constant. 
any ideas?

Comment: do you mean $x\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: yes, fixed that typo.thanks.

Comment: That relation is valid for all a and b in Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f\left(\frac{x+a}{b}\right)=f\left(\frac{f(x)+a}{b}\right)$$

So as you have noted, letting $a=c-f(x)$ gives

$$f\left(\frac{c+x-f(x)}{b}\right)=f\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)$$

If you suppose $f(x)\not=x$ for some $x\in \Bbb Q$, and define $\frac{u}{v}=x-f(x)$. By taking $c=pv(x-f(x))$ and $b=qv\left|x-f(x)\right|$ you get

$$f\left(\frac{pv(x-f(x))+x-f(x)}{qv\left|x-f(x)\right|}\right)=f\left(\frac{pv(x-f(x))}{qv\left|x-f(x)\right|}\right)$$

Simplifying that (and replacing $p$ by $-p$ if needed) gives

$$f\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{qv}\right)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$$

By recurrence, you can prove

$$f\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{q}\right)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$$

So, again by recurrence,

$$f\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{r}{s}\right)=f\left(\frac{ps}{qs}+\frac{qr}{qs}\right)=f\left(\frac{ps}{qs}\right)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$$

Since for $x\in \Bbb Q\setminus \Bbb Z$, you can't have $f(x)=x$, you are always in this case.

So the solitions are exactly the constant functions.